# how to change color of text when enter space in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am doing spell check application.
i want to change the color of text after enter space.
i got that wrong word.
now i want how to change color of that text in textbox.
using javascript.

Comment: See the How To Ask section in the FAQ to see how best to ask a question on StackOverlow.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript can modify the CSS very easily. Please check my example:

```
<input type="text" value="123" id="text1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("text1").style.color = "green";
</script>
```

Comment: A better solution would be to have a separate CSS class for incorrectly spelled words and to switch the CSS class when needed. +1 because the solution provided is in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Or use some of the libraries like JQuery.
Using JQuery, it's simple.

Having

```
<input name="my-text" type="text" id="my-text">
```

Catch the key down event

```
$("input#my-text").keydown(function(event)
{
   switch (event.keyCode) {
      // space
      case 32: $(this).css("color","#f00"); //or set any other property
         break;
   }
}
```

If you want to highlight single word, you'll need to wrap it into span and change property just for this element.

And yes, to highlight a sigle word you need to use paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the colour of just a word in a **textarea**.

But if you want to change the colour of text just in a text input, then the method outlined by rea_andrew should suffice.
Just do a

```
document.getElementById("textboxid").style.color = "green";
```

Comment: +1 for bolding "textarea". It was (very) easy to miss in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You'd basically need to do the same kind of thing TinyMCE and friends do building richer editors on top of the textarea. You are far better off using a pre-made library to do this for you. It is a lot more complicated than just changing the color, because you need to build a whole editor underneath that.